# How to convert Aperture license to app store license?

Tags: software, aperture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I update apps that I've already purchased through the Mac App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/can-i-update-apps-that-ive-already-purchased-through-the-mac-app-store)

Long ago I bought the retail box version of Aperture and have been steadily upgrading until the current version.  I no longer have the DVD, but I do have a valid license and serial number.

I just bought a new Mac Mini and quickly installed all my previously-purchased apps from the Mac App store.  I'd like to download Aperture this way, but don't want to buy it again.

Question: Is there any means to convert my current license to an App store license? I was hoping that when the App Store was first deployed, it would recognize my apple software and pull it into the App store model, but it did not.  (Aperture and iWork updates happen outside the app store because I didn't buy them there).

Hope that all makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/do-i-have-to-repurchase-apple-apps-through-the-mac-app-store-to-get-updates-ther

Answer (score 1):

From an [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6039/1453) by [Kyle Cronin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin) from another [Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6034/1453), with added emphasis:

> From [Daring
>   Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2011/01/06/panic-mac-app-store):
>
> > […] for apps that use the  same bundle ID for the both the Mac  App
> >     Store and non-App Store versions,  the Mac App Store will not install 
> >     updates to already-installed non-App  Store versions, but it will
> >     recognize  them as being already installed. **If  you want to get
> >     updates via the Mac  App Store, you’ll have to re-buy the  app through
> >     the App Store.**

Comment: Quite interestingly, this was a community wiki answer prior migrating. Also quite interestingly this was migrated here, even though I had quoted an answer from a question that would be an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a published method for 3rd party apps or Apple non-Pro apps (e.g. iWork).

Maybe worth a try if your current license is for Aperture 3 to use your 11-digit Aperture Support ID and contact technical support to ask. Please update here if this works to benefit future readers. Thanks.